# Why does React Native build as .tsx when creating a project?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to create a project with React Native. But when the project is created, it should be in the form of an App.js file, but it becomes App.tsx. I don't know why.

Is there any way I can use it back as before?

I watch this steps:
[react native setup[1](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?platform=ios)

I run this command:

```
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

Thanks,

Comment: React Native has TS enabled by default starting 0.71, You can still however use .js files and components as much as you want.
https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/12/version-071

Comment: @MostafaElkaramany Of course, but I'm worried if changing the default App.tsx file to .js, configuring it the hard way would be to the detriment of the project.